# Using action button to set value of widget in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Essentially I have a datetime based data frame. There are some widgets that control the plots based on equipment operating. When a datetime is chosen, the plots automatically update to show the equipment operating at that point. The user can change the plots to show different equipment lineups. The idea is to have an action button to "reset" the widgets to the currently selected equipment lineup based on the datetime the user has selected. Below is my MRE.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

test_data <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Action Button Test"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("num", label = h3("Select Row:"), value = 4),
            actionButton("action", label = "Reset State")
        ),
        mainPanel(uiOutput('checkBox'))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    current_state <- reactive({
        test_data[input$num]
    })
    output$checkBox <- renderUI({
        checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "State", value = current_state())
    })
    observeEvent(input$action, {
        current_state <- test_data[input$num]
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I believe I need to change the code in the `observeEvent` portion, but I'm open to ideas on how to better arrange this.

Comment: I think you need `updateCheckboxInput` in the `observeEvent`. Try `updateCheckboxInput(session, "checkbox", value = 4)` . Substitute value for the desired value (i.e., your default state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make the checkbox be dependant on the `current_state()`, we can achieve that with the first `observeEvent(current_state(),{...`. The reset part we just update the `input$num` using the second `observeEvent(input$action, {...` and since the checkbox is already dependant on the `current_state()` it will auto reset also...

```
library(shiny)
test_data <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
original_state <- 4

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Action Button Test"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("num", label = h3("Select Row:"), value = original_state,max = length(test_data)),
            actionButton("action", label = "Reset State")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            checkboxInput("checkbox", label = "State", value = test_data[original_state])
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    current_state <- reactive({
        test_data[input$num]
    })

    observeEvent(current_state(),{
        updateCheckboxInput(session, "checkbox", value = current_state())
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$action, {
        updateNumericInput(session,'num', value = original_state)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```